# XMLHttpRequest GET value will not input into mysqli_query SQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli, xmlhttprequest

I cannot get a switch id to insert into a mysqli query dynamically. If I insert the text in the SQL if returns the result, but $_GET does not work. From:

```
 function format_switch(sw_id)
{
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var sw_id = (sw_id);
  xhttp.open("GET", "return.php?sw_id="+sw_id, true);
  console.log(sw_id);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

the correct sw_id (switch_1) appears in the console log.

But this PHP code:

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); 
$switchnumber = $_GET['sw_id'];
$address = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "CBR1000f";
$database = "pinetdb";
$con = new mysqli($address,$user,$password,$database);
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT switchnumber,state FROM pinetdb.Switches WHERE switchnumber = '$switchnumber'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["switchnumber"]. ", " .$row["state"] ."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

returns:

```
Notice: Undefined index: swt_id in /var/www/pinet/html/return.php on line 4
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 2 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 )
```

If I type the expected value of sw_id into the SQL the code returns my expected result:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); 
$switchnumber = $_GET[sw_id];
$address = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "CBR1000f";
$database = "pinetdb";
$con = new mysqli($address,$user,$password,$database);
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT switchnumber,state FROM pinetdb.Switches WHERE switchnumber = 'switch_1'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row["switchnumber"]. ", " .$row["state"] ."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

returns:

```
Notice: Undefined index: swt_id in /var/www/pinet/html/return.php on line 4
switch_1, 1
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 2 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )
```

as expected.

I have made it to this point (beginning with a new linux installation) from other responses, but can't find a way forward with this. The very similar php that executes an update query works, but I cannot echo the updated field. Please let me know what is wrong with my script/s.

Comment: Get rid of the `print_r ($result);` it has no function there. You have already echoed the data from the fetched resultset

Comment: And as it appears that query only has one result you dont need a while loop to fetch the result set

Comment: `$switchnumber = $_GET[sw_id];` should be `$switchnumber = $_GET['sw_id'];`

Comment: `$result_free();` also makes no sense and is a syntax error.

Comment: You dont seem to be using SESSION so I am also not sure why this line is here `session_unset();`

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in your php

```
$switchnumber = $_GET[sw_id];
```

to

```
$switchnumber = $_GET['sw_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I added some code copied from W3Schools into my js, and got the field to update under the button rather than on another page. Good enough! There was nothing wrong with my php - I suppose it does not retain the $_GET details after the script is completed, so will not appear when the .php file is opened in a browser.

Here is my revised javascript:

```
 function return_switch(swt_id)
    {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var swt_id = (swt_id);
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById("switchstate").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "return.php?swt_id="+swt_id, true);
  console.log(swt_id);
  xhttp.send();
  }
```

and here is the html with the inclusion of a `<p><\p>` to contain the dynamically returned database field:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="change_switch.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1> Click the button to turn on the Switch</h1>
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="update_switch(this.id); return_switch(this.id)"  id="switch_1">Switch 1</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="update_switch(this.id); return_switch(this.id)"  id="switch_2">Switch 2</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="update_switch(this.id); return_switch(this.id)"  id="switch_3">Switch 3</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="update_switch(this.id); return_switch(this.id)"  id="switch_4">Switch 4</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="return_switch(this.id); update_switch(this.id)"  id="switch_5">Switch 5</button>
    <br>
    <p id="switchstate"></p>
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="location.href='/index.html'">Home</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```